# How can we get one value back of two values in Android java?

Tags: java, android, math

How can we get one value back of two values? For example, if the user writes 100, how can we replace 100 with 50+50 in the text box? That is, suppose the user types 100 and on pressing the button, instead of 100, the text box should show 50+50 or 75+25 and so on، which is equal to 100 .A friend suggest me but I want to provide a low and a high value to the user. That is, if the user writes 100, it should be displayed as 75+25 or 80+20 etc. Thanks

```
    int customerInput = 100; //getvalue from user
        int splitValue = customerInput/2;
       saif.setText(splitValue+"+"+splitValue);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the lows and highs that you need?

In your example it's 1/4 and 3/4 so that would give you:

```
  int customerInput = 100; //getvalue from user
  int splitValue1 = customerInput/4;
  int splitValue2 = (customerInput/4)*3;
  saif.setText(splitValue+"+"+splitValue);
```

If you need it to be random you can use the Java function

> int random = Random.nextInt(n)

This returns a random int in the range [0, n-1].
So in your case you would need a random number between 0 and 100

```
int customerInput = 100; //getvalue from user 
int random = new Random().nextInt(100); // [0, 100]
int random2 = 100 - random; // the other percent of your number
saif.setText(random+"+"+random2);
```

Comment: Thanks and work Perfect after changing according to my stage.

Comment: The first method breaks if the input value is not a multiple of 4! Input of `100`, `101`, `102` and `103` all give you `25` and `75`.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use your code with a small twist

```
int customerInput = 100; //getvalue from user
int half = customerInput/2;
int splitValue = new Random().nextInt(1, half+1);
saif.setText((customerInput - splitValue) + " + " + splitValue);
```

> Note this won't work for numbers below 1. If you do need them, use condition for 1 and 0 and simple abs for negatives

#### Another way is to use sqrt

```
int customerInput = 100; //getvalue from user
int splitValue = (int) Math.floor(Math.sqrt(customerInput));
saif.setText((customerInput - splitValue) + " + " + splitValue);
```

Comment: Sorry , Get this error.    method Random.nextInt() is not applicable

Comment: @BestThinking Depending on your Java version, it's `java.util.Random`, if it only accepts one param then use `new Random().nextInt(half) + 1` if *Random* it doesn't exist at all you can still use `(int) ((Math.random() * half) + 1)`

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is to split a value into two: a smaller number and a larger number.

You need to decide on a strategy for getting one of the numbers, for example, a fraction (which could be fixed or random). Thereafter, you compute the other number by subtraction.
You could use a fixed fraction (decimal).

```
int number = getUserInput();
double fraction = getFraction();
int numA = (int)(fraction * number);
int numB = number - numA;
```

Your `getFraction` method could either return a fixed fraction or a random fraction (if you need randomness).

This could either be:

```
double getFraction(){
   return 0.25; //This should be a public static final field in your class
}
```

or something like:

```
double getRandomFraction(){
   Random random = new Random(); //This could be a variable in the class
   int nominator = 1 + random.nextInt(9); //Gives you a random int between 1 and 9
   int denominator = 10;
   return (double)nominator / denominator;
}
```